# Error "Cannot read property 'uid' of null" while using firebase in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to Read my firebase data once for telegram bot, but I got this error:

```
D:\Projects 2016\Web\BOT\node-telegram-bot-api-sedric-bot\src\index.js:39
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null
```

And I used This From Google Tutorial, and this is my Function:

```
function readonce() {
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = snapshot.val().username;
  // ...
});
}
readonce()
```

I Read all of Tutorials on the net, But I Couldn't understand to read data by java script

Comment: I there's no user signed in, `.currentUser` is null.

Comment: How to add my user to node.js Project? I added `firebase.initializeApp(config);` to my project

Comment: I haven't any user connection, Just I want to read data and send via telegram bot, I Don't understand How To get my data.

Comment: If you don't have a user connection, then I do not understand what you are trying to do when you are reading data from the /users/ reference. Do you mind clarifying?

Comment: Because i read google tutorial, in a tutorial said you can read data with this code. My question is how can i read this json from firebase?!, that is very simple question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) in your Node script. The Admin SDK runs as an administrative level super-user, which doesn't have a defined identity. As such there is no `firebase.auth().currentUser`.

This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): a node script is not running as a specific user. So whose user name are you trying to look up? And what is it that you're trying to do with the user name?